# Separate positions for elements on the same "line"

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a number of textboxes with associated labels. The `div` in which they are contained has a style attribute that centres all content, which is excellent for the textboxes and some additional tools.

However, I cannot seem to left-align the label. It currently looks like this:
[image]

Where I wish the actual result to be something more like this:

[image]

```
<asp:Label ID="rotMkrLbl" runat="server" style="text-align:left">Lorem Ipsum</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="rotamkrBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Appears to do nothing. I'm as yet unsure how to use `align-content` or `align-self`, however giving these properties the attribute of `flex-start` has yielded no effect.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a CSS rule for the label to make it float left.
This will allow the label to fall back to the left margin but for the input field to remain centred.

```css
div { text-align:center;}
label { float:left;}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for='box1'>Label 1</label>
    <input type='text' id='box1' />
</div>

<div>
    <label for='box2'>Label 2</label>
    <input type='text' id='box2' />
</div>
```

As you are currently using inline styles, you could just add it like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="rotMkrLbl" runat="server" style="float:left">Lorem Ipsum</asp:Label> 
<asp:TextBox ID="rotamkrBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This placed my labels either *inside* or *on top of* the textboxes.

Comment: You can see from my code snippet that my example works, if its still not working for you, you may have something else in your code causing the issue which you did not include in your question.

Comment: Ooops. I'm in IE, I just checked Chrome and FF, I guess IE is wrong... Could that be possible?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more suitable solution, tested in IE, Chrome and FF :-)